# Brief possible service interruption

Tags: discussion, announcements, maintenance

**Micro Version:** Possible service interruption. All Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow sites might be briefly unavailable during a 30-minute period on Wednesday, November 18, 2020 starting at 8PM US/Eastern (01:00 AM UTC).

**Short Version:**
We will be upgrading firmware on some network hardware. This is not expected to cause an outage, however, a brief interruption is possible. The upgrade will begin on Wednesday, November 18, 2020 starting at 8PM US/Eastern (01:00 AM UTC) and should take approximately 30 minutes.

Questions or concerns? Please post a comment or answer below.

Comment: Does the maintenance include upgrading the Elastic search?

Comment: Hi Jade Sprague, welcome to Meta! I'm not sure which search brought you here but the problem you describe will not be answered on this specific site. Thanks for the notification, however, so +1! (Sorry, couldn't resist comparing this to the average post we see from new contributors here...)

Comment: @Glorfindel The cheek!  But +1 anyway... ;)

Comment: Are you sure 8PM US/Eastern is midnight UTC? I was strongly under the impression that [US/Eastern is currently UTC-5](https://time.is/ET), not UTC-4.

Comment: For Europeans wondering, that's 1AM GMT today.

Comment: Would it be possible to schedule future maintenance outages to Homework Sundays?  All Sundays would be good:)

Comment: @Makyen: Indeed! Eastern Daylight Time is UTC-4, but Eastern Standard Time is UTC-5. And Daylight Saving Time ended in those parts of the US that observe it (NJ, at least) on Sunday, November 1.

Comment: @Braiam Didn't we already discuss the use of the maintenance tag on another post? I thought we had reached a consensus, yet you again removed another relevant tag.